# Data from Cursor added to ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter shows white text (how to make it black)

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

Data from Cursor added to ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter shows white text (how to make it black) - see the image

[image]
Here is the Simple cursor adapter code

```
public void displayWords(Cursor c){

    // Creates a new SimpleCursorAdapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        getApplicationContext(),                    // The application's Context object
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,        // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
        c,                                          // The result from the query
        new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_WORD},      // A string array of column names in the cursor
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });          // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout


    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
    setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    /* Using SimpleCursorAdapter to get Data from DB.
     * stackoverflow.com/questions/12077955/android-using-simplecursoradapter-to-get-data-from-database-to-listview
     */
}
```

And the style resources used in AndroidManifes file

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Egor said, if you could show some more code, that would be helpful.

In the meantime:
It looks like you are using list-view items that have a 'light' (holo) theme while your app (or just that activity() uses a 'dark' (holo) theme. The textviews' text-color is picked up from the app's dark theme (white font color) on top of white background.

To figure out why that happens, we need more code (AndroidManifest.xml, for example) from you.

Update after OP's comment:

```
public void displayWords(Cursor c){

    // Creates a new SimpleCursorAdapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        getApplicationContext(),                    // The application's Context object
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,        // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
        c,                                          // The result from the query
        new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_WORD},      // A string array of column names in the cursor
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }){
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View newView = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
            ((TextView)newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
return newView;
        }
    };          // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout


    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
    setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    /* Using SimpleCursorAdapter to get Data from DB.
     * stackoverflow.com/questions/12077955/android-using-simplecursoradapter-to-get-data-from-database-to-listview
     */
  }
```

I added an override of the adapter's ***newView*** method to your code, which would allow you to set/change the text's color. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: I will update it with the manifest.xml  code ...I think that the other code is irelevant (SQLHelper class, ContentProvider, etc) because basically I need here a way to programaticaly set the Text color of the andoroid.R.id.text1 - relating the post below from Droider ( but with his code it gives me a NullPointerException - cannot get the instance of android.R.id.text1).

Comment: No problem :-) Note that my answer is a bit of a hack. You should figure out why the list-items have a white background. Based on your screenshot, the theme is 'dark' and the list-items should have a dark background (with white text). Another way to fix it is to theme your app 'light' (Theme.Light).

Comment: Well the app theme is already light ..(I updated the code above)..but I am not sure why it does not show the text in black automaticlly...but nevermind, this is fine :D

Answer (score 2):

The theme used by `this` is not the same theme used by the context returned from `getApplicationContext()`. The simple answer is always use `this` to maintain your theme.

The OP is using a Light theme, which `this` returns.  `getApplicationContext()` does not contain an inflated theme.  When it is inflated it includes the system default theme.

More detailed information can be found [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem recently. Used two ListActivities. Clicking an item on the first one started the second ListActivity. First one displayed the theme correctly, but the second one did the same as the screenshot shows in the OP.

Only difference was the context argument I used in my array adapter creation. First activity used the this reference and the second one I used the getApplicationContext (like the OP). Changing it to the this reference fixed the output.

Could someone with more knowledge maybe expand on why the getApplicationContext "theme" seems to differ from the theme accessed via this(ListActivity). I would have thought that as the theme is set in the application tag in the manifest this would be the theme used by all activities unless set otherwise. I admit my knowledge of the getContext... methods is limited and I could be interpreting this completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);`

`tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`