# Why is my listview so dim when populating it with cursorloader?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

After so much of work, I finally populated a listview using CursorLoader and SimpleCursorAdapter, though I still don't understand the CursorLoader clearly. I am trying to display a list view of word meanings, but the list view is so unclear(dim). It looks like a blur background. The list item becomes clear only when I click it. Can anyone help me why is that and how to solve?

The 'wordmeanings.xml' contaings a listview and 'wordmeaningrow.xml' contains two textviews each for word and meaning.

Here is my code:

```
    public class WordMeaning_CursorLoader extends ListActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    // Identifies a particular loader being used in this component
    private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;
    Uri CONTENT_URI;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wordmeanings);

        String[] columns = {Constants.WORD_NAME, Constants.MEANING_NAME};
        int[] to = {R.id.tvword_wordmeaningrow, R.id.tvmeaning_wordmeaningrow};

        sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.wordmeaningrow, null, columns, to, 0);

        this.setListAdapter(sAdapter);
        // initializing the loader
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this);
    }   // end onCreate

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
        switch(loaderId){
        case URL_LOADER:
            //returns new cursor loader
            String myUri = "content://com.test.provider.wordmeaning/tbl_word_meaning";
            CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(myUri);
            return new CursorLoader(
                    WordMeaning_CursorLoader.this,
                    CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

        default:
            return null;

        }   // end switch
    }   // end onCreateLoader

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {

        sAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }   // end onLoadFinished

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        sAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}   // end WordMeaning_CursorLoader
```

**wordmeanings.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**wordmeaningrow.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvword_wordmeaningrow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="word" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvmeaning_wordmeaningrow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:text="meaning" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The dim thing I mentioned above looks something like in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-njNGMhPCU) at around 8:30. Thanks. I am using genymotion emulator.

Snapshots:

[image: dim list view]

[image: list item appears perfect when clicked]

[image: list view generated without using cursor loader]

The third snapshot is generated using the following code:

```
public class WordMeaning_CursorAdapter extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.wordmeanings);

        String myUri = "content://com.test.provider.wordmeaning/tbl_word_meaning";
        Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(myUri);
        //get ContentResolver instance
        ContentResolver crInstance = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = crInstance.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // the desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {Constants.WORD_NAME, Constants.MEANING_NAME};

        // the xml defined views for each field to be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvword_wordmeaningrow, R.id.tvmeaning_wordmeaningrow};

        // create adapter with cursor pointing to desired data
        SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.wordmeaningrow, c, columns, to, 0);

        // set this adapter as the list activity's adapter
        this.setListAdapter(cAdapter);
    }   // end onCreate

}   // end WordMeaning_CursorAdapter class
```

Comment: its something with your layout, which you didnt post

Comment: I displayed the desired list view with same layout, only then I was not using cursorloader. I used contentprovider and simple cursor adapter. So, i don't think there's anything wrong with the layout.

Comment: same layout as what?

Comment: First, please post a screenshot **of your own app** somewhere and link to it from your question. Do not post a link to something that is not tied to your question. Second, please post the layout that you are using for your `ListView` rows, as that is what is dim, and we cannot help you make it be less dim if we cannot see how you set it up in the first place.

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply, just the regular power cut off and the electricity just came. I have uploaded some snapshots and the xml layout.

Comment: Try setting text color for tvword_wordmeaningrow and tvmeaning_wordmeaningrow to black and give a try.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that worked. But still does anyone know why that previous dimness occurs or was it that the textColor automatically changed to white?

Comment: Default theme might be issue. This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070237/data-from-cursor-added-to-listview-with-simplecursoradapter-shows-white-text-ho